# change burger icon side for nav drawer

Tags: java, android, togglebutton, drawerlayout, drawer

I used a Android Studio Template for Side menu drawer.

Problem : I want the whole drawer to appear on right.

Progress : I can change the android:layout_gravity to "end" for drawer layout, but i cannot move the three-line-icon (also called shelf, burger or Navigation Drawer icon) in ActionBar to the right side.

Visual source to maybe provide better understanding of my problem:
[image: Drawer is on right, but not the burger icon]

Here comes the code :

Drawer activity (Lecture_graph.java) :

```
public class Lectures_graph extends AppCompatActivity implements course_list.OnFragmentInteractionListener, lectures_graph.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lectures_graph);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_course_list, R.id.nav_lectures_greph)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

XML for this activity (activity_lecture_graph.xml) :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
//this lets drawer to be on right
        tools:openDrawer="end">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_lectures_graph"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_lectures_graph"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_lectures_graph_drawer"
//this allows drawer to be on right
android:layout_gravity="end" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app bar layout (app_bar_lectures_graph.xml) :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".systems.lectures.Lectures_graph">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_lectures_graph" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Drawer xml (activity_lectures_graph_drawer.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".systems.lectures.Lectures_graph">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_lectures_graph" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Will be thankful for any help.

Comment: Its is called Navigation Drawer icon*

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.
try this (kotlin) :

```
 val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer_layout, toolbar,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    )
    toggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = false
    toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp)
    toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener {
        if (drawer .isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer .closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            drawer .openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        }
    }
    drawer .addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()
```

for (Java)

```
 Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

 DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

 ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    );
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp);
    toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (drawer .isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer .closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                drawer .openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }


        }
    });

    drawer .addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

Comment: `ActionBarDrawerToggle` only works with the main navigation button, and only with a left/start-aligned drawer.

Comment: I just noticed that you're overriding the click behavior, there, so that would work with an end-aligned drawer – if you were to fix the gravity – but it's still on the wrong side for what the OP wants.

Comment: Yeah, i found something simmilar yesterday, but onClick listener was containing GravityCompat.RIGHT. Basically i was able to open menu from right to left (because it had layout_gravity:end) with the button in left of actionbar. So i had a icon in left of actionbar working with a menu sliding from right side, just like you can see in picture above. I just need to move icon in actionbar from left to right, but seems pretty hard to do so.

Comment: ok i will play around with this solution anyway, maybe i will be able to work something out.